# Trouble Opening a File As The Apache User

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions, python

I am having trouble running a python file as the apache user.

When I run this command: `sudo -u apache /etc/httpd/conf.d/upsell_by_id.py` I get this error:

`File "/etc/httpd/conf.d/upsell_by_id.py", line 8, in <module>
    keyword_groups = pickle.load(open("/home/zumodo/upsell_backup/upsells.pkl", "rb" ))
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/zumodo/upsell_backup/upsells.pkl'`

However, the file in question has the following permissions:

```
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 skline skline 6.4M Dec  5 08:50 upsells.pkl
```

I am at a loss as to why the apache user is not allowed to open this file.

Comment: isn't this essentially the same question as your other? http://serverfault.com/questions/337902/determing-the-execution-environment-of-apache/337903#comment333515_337903

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the dot in the end of the permission list show that you have enabled SELinux extensions. They probably prevent you from reading the file. It could also be that some folders in the file path are not descend-able by the Apache user.

You have to give far more information before you get good answers.